# Oracle 11g Cold Restore?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Is there a way to restore an Oracle 11g instance from raw data files only? What is the minimum amount of information needed to reconstruct the config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've shutdown the database cleanly (ie not a SHUTDOWN ABORT), you need to backup...

The Datafiles:

```
select name from v$datafile
```

The Database Control Files:

```
select name from v$controlfile
```

The Online Redo Logs:

```
select member from v$logfile
```

You'll also want to backup your init.ora or spfile

Reference:  http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/admin/backup_recovery/cold_backup.html